# Select cells relative to cells that match a condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to select all rows where the cell in column 3 has the text "foo". Then, in the rows that match, I want to select the cell two colums right of the "foo" cell. I then want to create the sum of these cells.

Example:

```
bla bla foo bla 100
bla bla bar bla  50
bla bla foo bla 200
bla bla baz bla  10
```

In the above I want to sum the values 100 and 200, based on the "foo" in column 3. I do not want the 50 and 10, because these rows have not "foo" in their third column.

I am searching for the formula for this, to be entered in another cell, so that the result displays there.

Comment: `=SUMIFS(E:E,C:C,"foo")`

Comment: I get "There is a problem with this Formula" (backtranslated from German). My concrete formula is: `=ZÄHLENWENNS(E2:E21,C2:C21,"foo")`

Comment: I guess you want `;` instead of `,`.

Comment: Are you sure? "Zaehlen" means "counting", not "summing". Don't you need `Summewenns` or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `SUMIFS`:

```
=SUMIFS(E:E,C:C,"foo")
```

or `SUMMEWENNS` and the formula separator `;` in your case:

```
=SUMMEWENNS(E2:E21;C2:C21;"foo")
```

This sums the values in `E2:E21`, where the matching rows in `C2:C21` have the value `"foo"`.